# Python Pandas: Error when exporting DataFrame to CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export

I am getting the following error when trying to export a pandas DataFrame to csv.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/riley/PycharmProjects/EarlyPaidLoanReport/EarlyPaidOff.py", line 91, in <module>
    LastTransactionDate.to_csv(LastTransactionDate, 'example.csv')
    File "C:\Users\riley\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1344, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
    File "C:\Users\riley\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py", line 1526, in save
    compression=self.compression)
    File "C:\Users\riley\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 424, in _get_handle
    f = open(path, mode, errors='replace')
    TypeError: invalid file:        AutoNumber                       LoanAgreementID  \
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this error. I've been writing to csv using pandas many times in the past. Could someone please help to fix this error?

```
LastTransactionDate.to_csv(LastTransactionDate, 'example.csv')
```

Comment: the arguments are the other way round. Filename comes first...

Comment: `LastTransactionDate.to_csv('example.csv')`. Why are you replicating your `DF`?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. Unless I am missing something, just do this:

`LastTransactionDate.to_csv('example.csv')`